# How to easily label geoJSON with Leaflet?

Tags: json, leaflet, mapbox, label

This map is of Population Totals in a neighborhood. The layer 'Population2000Layer' includes the attribute field 'Total'. Just need to reach in there and display the total at the polygon's center with some like

choroplethize(feature.properties.Total)

The goal is to use to the Total Population attribute to label each polygon:

```
       function choroplethize(d) {
<!-- jenks breaks from 2010 were applied to 2000 as well-->
return d > 1175  ? '#045a8d' :
       d > 1083  ? '#2b8cbe' :
       d > 801  ? '#74a9cf' :
       d > 711  ? '#bdc9e1' :
                  '#f1eef6';
}

// styling for the total Population layers
function styleTotalPop(feature) {
    return {
        weight: 3,
        opacity: 0.25,
        color: 'black',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.9,
        fillColor: choroplethize(feature.properties.Total)
    }
}

<!-- add blocks' Populations for 2000 and 2010 as GeoJSON layer -->
var Population2000Layer = L.geoJson(Population2000, {
    style: styleTotalPop,
    onEachFeature: geojsonPopup2000,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case my JS doesn't make choroplethize categories, but I declared some cases with other syntax. I think this could be helpful for you.

**These are the attributes**:

```
var calzada = new L.geoJson(data, {
                style: function (feature) {
                    var c;
                    switch (feature.properties.dpv_cal) {
                    case 'Natural':
                    c = '#ffffff';
                    break;
                    case 'Mejorada':
                    c = '#db6adb';
                    break;
                    case 'Pavimentada':
                    c = '#ff0127';
                    break;
                    default:
                    c = '#000000';
                    }
                 return {color: c, opacity: 1, weight: 2};
                }
              }).addTo(map);
```

This is just a part of my code, obviously, and worked for me. It is a line shape and refers to different routes' categories.